# How does drupal commerce view capture taxonomy url?

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms, search, views

I have a strange bug where everything is working fine in production, but when I copy (using drush arb) and reinstall the website somewhere else. it doesn't work.

Whenever I try display all products or some corresponding to a taxonomy url. Nothing happen. I mean the result find 0 items and return the message corresponding to the an empty result. It looks like the view is ignoring taxonomy search. I'm trying to debug what's happening but I don't understand how the search work. The view is plugged to use a fullsearch search. However, when doing `/products` or using a facet, the standard search shouldn't return anything. I expect the search results has be modified to allow either return all result if no search are selected or if we are using a taxonomy alias , example `/products?field_product[1]:2`, but I can't figure which bit of code do this.
Is it suppose to be a standard feature of the search api, is in in view ? drupal commerce ?

Any help, welcome !

Comment: Maybe you need to re-index after moving your site. Go to Search API settings  (admin/config/search/search_api) and index all items.

Comment: I've done that as well, but doesn't do anything. I just need to where is the code to use taxonomy search in view.